# String conversion into DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, date-parsing, parseexception

I have a joda DateTime value stored in mysql as String.

But when I try to get this string from mysql table, its format changes and when I try to convert this string into DateTime, it throws:-

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2012-10-04 00:00:00.0" is malformed at "  00:00:00.0"
```

In the Mysql table I can see the values as"2012-10-04 00:00:00", but when I get this time from mysql it is printing as "2012-10-04 00:00:00.0".

Please help me.

Comment: Can we see the conversion code?

Answer (score 2):

```
   `String dob="your date String";
    //2013-jan-12 == 2013-01-12
    String dobis=null;
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        if(dob!=null && !dob.isEmpty() && dob != "")
        {
        c.setTime(df.parse(dob));
        int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        month=month+1;
        dobis=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+month+"-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }

    } `
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Just pass a string to this method and get the value of date

```
public String DateToDateFormat(String dateandTime) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
    try {
        calendar.setTime(df.parse(dateandTime));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    int yearofsendingmsg = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    // int monthofsendingmsg = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int dayofsendingmsg = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    String monthofsendingmsg = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(d);
    String date = dayofsendingmsg + " " + monthofsendingmsg + " "
            + yearofsendingmsg;
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
Date date = df.parse("2012-10-04 00:00:00.0");
```

Comment: He is not hard coding the input. It is fetched from a database which is not is the expected format and hence getting that exception. Your code will fail for the input mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The right format is:

```
 "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String newF="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
String oldF="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat(oldF);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2=new SimpleDateFormat(newF);
String txt1=ClassWhichContainsTheVariableYouGotTheResultInTo.txtVariable.getText();

String date1=sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(txt1));
java.util.Date javaDate1=(Date)sdf2.parse(date1); //this converts it as java.util.Date
java.sql.Date sqlDate1=new java.sql.Date(theDate1.getTime()); //this converts it to java.sql.Date (if needed)
```

This way you can parse the String variable to a java.Date of your choice.
The `ClassWhichContainsTheVariableYouGotTheResultInTo` means the class name of (for eg. Main.java) in which you are returning the sql value in, and the `txtVariable.getText()` is a reference to a variable such as textfield or label, or whatever you returned the value into. After the conversion is done, you can then just use either `javaDate1` or `sqlDate1`, depending on which date type you want.